# Find an injective function f ∈ P ([0, 3]) → A while $A = \{ X \in P ([0,3]) \mid |X| = \aleph _{1} \}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A = \{ X \in P ([0,3]) \mid |X| = \aleph _{1} \}$. That is to say, all the subsets of the closed interval $[0,3]$ with cardinality $\aleph$. How can I find an injective function $f$ from $P ([0, 3])$ to $A$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather that downvotes if you edit the question to show us what you have thought to try and where you are stuck.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I apologize Ethan. I actually don't even know how to approach this. I'm trying to understand the idea of bijection and injection as a self learner. Thank you

Comment: This is a pretty complex problem for a self learner starting on understanding bijections. I suggest you look in your sources for easier problems to work on first.

Comment: Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have the wording correct? The set $P([0,3])$ of size $2^{2^{\aleph}}$ while the cardinality of $A$ is $2^{\aleph}$.

Comment: Why is the set $P([0,3])$ of size $2^{2^{\aleph}}$? [0,3] is of size $\aleph$ so $P([0,3])$ is of size $2^{\aleph}$

Comment: @Yogev What do you mean by $\aleph$ then? Do you mean $\aleph = \aleph_0 = | \mathbb{N}|$ or is it something else (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number))?

Comment: I refer to $\aleph _{1}$. I'm sorry it's not clear. I'll fix it

Comment: You can do something like this: Let $B\in P[0,3]$. If $|B|$ is uncountable, then map it to $\frac{1}{3}B$. So, all uncountables go to elements of $A$ that are subsets of $[0,1]$. If $B$ is finite, then map it to the set $\frac{1}{10}B+1.1$ union $[1.5, 2]$. Finally, if $B$ is countable, map it to $\frac{1}{6000}B+2.1$ union $[2.5,3]$. You can prettify the scaling to waste as little space in $[0,3]$ as possible. All is needed is to shrink enough such that the resulting sets don't have a chance to intersect.

Comment: @despaigne That settles the question or not, depending on the Continuum Hypothesis. "uncountable" may or may not be the same as "cardinality = $\aleph_1$" for sets of reals...

Comment: @Yogev $B$'s from the different cases, are mapped to different chunks of $[0,3]$; either $[0,1]$, $[1.1,2]$, or $[2.1,3]$. Then, $B$'s from the same case are mapped to essentially a scaling of $B$ (and perhaps union with a common interval). Therefore their images are different because the part that is a scaling of $B$ are different.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness

Comment: You say that $[0,3]$ is of size $\aleph_1$. This is not true! (Or at least it can be proved that this cannot be proved from ZFC. See "continuum hypothesis" somewhere...)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you meant $\aleph_1$ and not $c$? Note that $c=|[0,3]|$, while $|[0,3]|$ may or may not be $\aleph_1$, depending on the Continuum Hypothesis.

If we say $B=\{X\subset [0,3]:|X|=c\}$ it's easy to give an injection from $\mathcal P([0,3])$ to $B$: $$f(S)=\frac13 S\cup [2,3],$$where $\frac13 S=\{\frac13 t:t\in S\}$. (This is certainly injective, since $S=(3f(S))\cap[0,3]$.)

In fact the existence of an injection from $\mathcal P([0,3])$ to your set $A$ is undecidable in ZFC.

**Terminology:** When I say something is "possible" I mean its negatiion cannot be proved in ZFC.

It's possible that $\aleph_1=c$; if so then $A=B$ and we're done, we constructed your bijection above.

It's also possible that $\aleph_1<c$. I don't really know, but I *suspect* it's possible that $2^{\aleph_1}<2^c$. (**Edit:** Yes, it's possible. Noah Schweber actually knows something about set theory.) If so then the cardinality of $A$ is less than the cardinality of $\mathcal P([0,3])$, so there is no such bijection.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ??? Can $2^{\aleph_1}<2^c$?

Comment: Yes, this can totally happen - e.g. if $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. Then $2^{\aleph_1}=c<2^c$. (Incidentally, I can't be pinged in comments if I'm not already in the comment thread - it's pure luck that I was looking at this at the right moment. :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for both tips...

Comment: Thank you. Just noting that the function you gave is injective but not bijective (as it is not surjective. For instance, [0,1] is not there)

Comment: No, of course it's not a bijection.